# What are the differences between electron-positron annihilation and electron-positron scattering?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, antimatter

Reading the wikipedia of [Bhabha scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering), I see that the electron-positron annihilation and electron-positron scattering are analyzed seperately. What are the differences between these two processes? Why aren't they the same process?

Comment: *How* can annihilation be the same as scattering? After annihilation the incoming two particles no longer exist, while after scattering, they do still exist.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering) (attached below) says that an $e^-$ and $e^+$ can scatter either via an exchange of a photon (second diagram) or they can totally annihilate each other, converting their energy into photons and then be recreated from the same photons. Both these processes account for a Bhabha scattering process.

On the other hand, you can have an $e^-$ and $e^+$ that simply annihilating each other. In this case, you will only be left with energy.

[image]